# Webview on Android app not responding

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I am very new to **Android** Studio and basically Android programming and I need to make restaurant ordering system with app for chiefs and **app for ordering**, so I started on making ordering app. I choose easy way, **webview**, because I know php, css, html and all that kinds of stuff. I have downloaded SDKs that are required, watched few tutorials and read few pages but I cannot find a fix! Website consists of html, css, js and few png images. 

Basically, **this is problem**:
 On browser(android and pc), website is responsive, but on webview app it is not. I can scroll, but I cannot click or buttons and items for sale wont load.

[Website link](http://catino.co.nf/narucivanje/)
[Android Studio Project(13mb, modified webview-master)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04fzq0d6zXTWTR5RGEzQk9sV2s)

Theories or fixes? I can give you some parts of code from website, just ask!

Also, it would be nice if somebody understands what is problem here to explain it to me in as much detail as possible, I love to learn! :)
***THANKS***

Answer (score 1):

Oh my God! What a blamage! Router at our place has just crashed so part of code didn't load! If anybody had problems like this, restart routers system.